# How to specifically style th and td only for one table class?

Tags: html, css

I have a really annoying and baffling problem. My website has two different classes of table. One has no border and the other does. But no matter what I do, I cannot separate the th and td styling from the other table.

The first table has no class styling; I default to whatever.

The second table has:

```
table.t01, th, td {
   border: 4px solid black;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

However, this affects the styling of th and td for the first table. WTF.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you apply the styling to your selectors more explicitly (see below):

```
table.t01, table.t01 th, table.t01 td {
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, so I'm designating it as the correct answer. CSS is so damn weird.

Answer (score 4):

By using commas in your selector, you're saying "this style applies to any `table` with class `t01`, but also ANY `th` and ANY `td`."

This can be useful to consolidate the styling of many elements that have the same style. For example, the following are equivalent:

```
// The verbose way
th { color: red; }
td { color: red; }
p.red { color: red; }
div#firstred { color: red; } 

// The concise way
th, td, p.red, div#firstred { color: red; }
```

If what you really looking for is to define a style for `th` and `td` descendants of a `table` with class `t01`, just separate the terms of the `table` and `th`/`td` selectors with a space:

Try:

```
table.t01 th, table.t01 td {
   border: 4px solid black;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: More accurately, you're defining a style for _descendents_ of a `table.t01`. The (immediate) _children_ of the table would be a `tr` or a `thead` etc.

Comment: This doesn't work. It kills the styling for the second table, i.e., no styling at all (like it was default).

Comment: @RichardEng Your question states that you only want to style the `th` and `td` elements of the table with class `t01`, correct? Not also add a border to the whole table?

Answer (score -1):

Here's another, slightly shorter alternative:

```
<style>
    #myTable th, td { 
        border: 4px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
</style>
...
<table id="myTable">
    ...
</table>
```